# How to export data from multidimentional array to csv

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, fputcsv

Im traying to export some data to csv. I can print the data in the web but when i save it to a csv file it shows this:

```
Column 1,"Column 2"
Array,"Acme (Sample)",0011U00000AnbfaQAB
Array,"Global (Sample)",0011U00000AnbfbQAB
```

How can i get rid of the "Array,"?

I get the data here and print it:

```
foreach ($records as $record)
{
print 'Name :';
print htmlspecialchars($record['Name']);
print ' - ';
print htmlspecialchars($record['Id']);
print '<br/>';
print "\n";
}
```

This is a code to save the data to csv:

```
$file = fopen('toNavasoft.csv', 'w');

// save the column headers
fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2'));

// save each row of the data
foreach ($records as $record)
{
fputcsv($file, $record);
}

// Close the file
fclose($file);
```

I just added this:

```
var_export ($records);
```

and the output is:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'attributes' => array ( 'type' => 'Account', 'url' => '/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/0011U00000AnbfaQAB', ), 'Name' => 'Acme (Sample)', 'Id' => '0011U00000AnbfaQAB', ), 1 => array ( 'attributes' => array ( 'type' => 'Account', 'url' => '/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/0011U00000AnbfbQAB', ), 'Name' => 'Global (Sample)', 'Id' => '0011U00000AnbfbQAB', ), )
```

I expect the output like:

```
Column 1,Column 2
Acme (Sample),0011U00000AnbfaQAB
Global (Sample),0011U00000AnbfbQAB
```

Comment: As long as we don't know what the array looks like then it's only a guessing game. Post a var_export of the array

Comment: I'm guessing there's a third element in each `$record` that is an array and when you try to `fputcsv()` it's putting all three elements.

Comment: i just update it with the output of the array.

Comment: @Oscar Read my answer to get a bit more detail on what I'm talking about. Mohammed Yassine CHABLI has a similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **fputcsv** , uing the code bellow :

```
<?php

$result = array(['column1', 'column2']);
 foreach($records as $record){
  $result[] = [$record['Name'],$record['Id']];
 }


$fp = fopen('toNavasoft.csv', 'w');

foreach ($result as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

> The point here is to select the data you want to persist in the cv
>   file into $result variable and then continue what you already try to
>   do .

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    $file = fopen('toNavasoft.csv', 'w');
    $array=array('Column 1', 'Column 2');


    fwrite($file,print_r($array,TRUE));


    // Close the file
    fclose($file);


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out an extra array that's inside of `$record`. You say your output is:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'attributes' => array ( 'type' => 'Account', 'url' => '/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/0011U00000AnbfaQAB', ), 'Name' => 'Acme (Sample)', 'Id' => '0011U00000AnbfaQAB', ), 1 => array ( 'attributes' => array ( 'type' => 'Account', 'url' => '/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/0011U00000AnbfbQAB', ), 'Name' => 'Global (Sample)', 'Id' => '0011U00000AnbfbQAB', ), )
```

That means you would need to unset `$record['attributes']` before running `fputcsv()` like this:

```
foreach ($records as $record)
{
  unset($record['attributes']);
  fputcsv($file, $record);
}
```

Comment: NICE! Love you!